# Can't get grid area to fill vertical space

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I'm trying to use css-grid to create 3 areas, 2 with fixed height and the bottom one to fill the available space with a grid of buttons that also adapt to the space available. The buttons will adapt horizontally but not vertically. Can you see what silly thing I am doing to stop it working?

```css
* {
  margin: 2px 2px 2px 2px;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  outline: 0;
  font-size: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
  background: transparent;
  letter-spacing: normal;
}

body {
  color: #00000;
  background-color: #335155
}

p {
  color: #669990;
  font-size: 50px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

p:after {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  width: 0px;
  height: auto;
}

.panel {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 80px 80px 1fr;
}

.top-panel {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 60% 1fr 40px;
  grid-template-rows: 80px;
  grid-row-gap: 20px;
  grid-column-gap: 20px;
  padding: 0px 50px 0px 20px;
}

#paragraph-1 {
  text-align: right;
  padding: 0px 10px 0px 0px;
}

#paragraph-2 {
  border-width: 1px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #669990;
  min-height: 75px;
  max-width: 100px;
  padding: 0px 20px 0px 0px;
  text-align: center;
}

#paragraph-3 {
  min-height: 75px;
  max-width: 100px;
  padding: 0px 10px 0px 0px;
  text-align: center;
}

.middle-panel {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr;
  grid-row-gap: 20px;
}

button {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #669990;
  border: none;
  color: #335155;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 20px;
}

button:hover {
  background-color: white;
}

.button-panel {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(4, minmax(20px, 300px);
  grid-row-gap: 10px;
  grid-column-gap: 10px;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}

.grid-position-1-1 {
  grid-column: 1;
  grid-row: 1;
}

.grid-position-2-1 {
  grid-column: 2;
  grid-row: 1;
}

.grid-position-3-1 {
  grid-column: 3;
  grid-row: 1;
}

.grid-position-1-2 {
  grid-column: 1;
  grid-row: 2;
}

.grid-position-2-2 {
  grid-column: 2;
  grid-row: 2;
}

.grid-position-3-2 {
  grid-column: 3;
  grid-row: 2;
}

.grid-position-1-3 {
  grid-column: 1;
  grid-row: 3;
}

.grid-position-2-3 {
  grid-column: 2;
  grid-row: 3;
}

.grid-position-3-3 {
  grid-column: 3;
  grid-row: 3;
}

.grid-position-1-4 {
  grid-column: 1;
  grid-row: 4;
}

.grid-position-2-4 {
  grid-column: 2;
  grid-row: 4;
}

.grid-position-3-4 {
  grid-column: 3;
  grid-row: 4;
}
```

```html
<div class="panel">
  <div class="grid-position-1-1">
    <!-- of panel-->
    <div class="top-panel">
      <div class="grid-position-1-1">
        <!-- of top-panel-->
        <p id="paragraph-1"></p>
      </div>
      <div class="grid-position-2-1">
        <!-- of top-panel-->
        <p id="paragraph-2"></p>
      </div>
      <div class="grid-position-3-1">
        <!-- of top-panel-->
        <p id="paragraph-3"></p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="grid-position-2-1">
      <!-- of panel-->
      <div class="middle-panel">
        <p id="another-paragraph"></p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="grid-position-3-1">
      <!-- of panel-->
      <div class="button-panel">
        <div class="grid-position-1-1">
          <!-- of button-panel-->
          <button id="button-1" class="input-button" value=x>x</button>
        </div>
        <div class="grid-position-2-1">
          <button id="button-2" class="input-button" value=x>x</button>
        </div>
        <div class="grid-position-3-1">
          <button id="button-3" class="input-button" value=x>x</button>
        </div>
        <div class="grid-position-1-2">
          <button id="button-4" class="input-button" value=x>x</button>
        </div>
        <div class="grid-position-2-2">
          <button id="button-5" class="input-button" value=x>x</button>
        </div>
        <div class="grid-position-3-2">
          <button id="button-6" class="input-button" value=x>x</button>
        </div>
        <div class="grid-position-1-3">
          <button id="button-7" class="input-button" value=x>x</button>
        </div>
        <div class="grid-position-2-3">
          <button id="button-8" class="input-button" value=x>x</button>
        </div>
        <div class="grid-position-3-3">
          <button id="button-9" class="input-button" value=x>x</button>
        </div>
        <div class="grid-position-1-4">
          <button id="button-10" class="input-button" value=x>x</button>
        </div>
        <div class="grid-position-2-4">
          <button id="button-10" class="input-button" value=x>x</button>
        </div>
        <div class="grid-position-3-4">
          <button id="button-10" class="input-button" value=x>x</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Amended code as per advice of Michael_B

```css
* {
    margin: 2px 2px 2px 2px;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    outline: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
    background: transparent;
    letter-spacing: normal;
}

body {color: #00000; background-color: #335155}

p {
    color: #669990;
    font-size: 50px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}

p:after {
    content:"";
    display:inline-block;
    width:0px;
    height:auto;
}
.panel {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: 80px 80px 1fr;
}

.top-panel {
    grid-column: 1;
    grid-row: 1;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 60% 1fr 40px;
    grid-template-rows: 80px;
    grid-row-gap: 20px;
    grid-column-gap: 20px;
    padding: 0px 50px 0px 20px;
}

#paragraph-1 {
    text-align: right;
    padding: 0px 10px 0px 0px;
}
#paragraph-2 {
    border-width: 1px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #669990;
    min-height: 75px;
    max-width: 100px;
    padding: 0px 20px 0px 0px;
    text-align: center;
}

#paragraph-3 {
    min-height: 75px;
    max-width: 100px;
    padding: 0px 10px 0px 0px;
    text-align: center;
}

.middle-panel {
    grid-column: 1;
    grid-row: 2;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr;
    grid-row-gap: 20px;
}
button {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #669990;
    border: none;
    color: #335155;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 20px;
}
button:hover {
    background-color: white;
}
.button-panel {
    grid-column: 1;
    grid-row: 3;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
    grid-template-rows: repeat(4, 1fr);
    grid-row-gap: 2px;
    grid-column-gap: 2px;
}  

.grid-position-1-1 {
    grid-column: 1;
    grid-row: 1;
}
.grid-position-2-1 {
    grid-column: 2;
    grid-row: 1;
}
.grid-position-3-1 {
    grid-column: 3;
    grid-row: 1;
}
.grid-position-1-2 {
    grid-column: 1;
    grid-row: 2;
}
.grid-position-2-2 {
    grid-column: 2;
    grid-row: 2;
}
.grid-position-3-2 {
    grid-column: 3;
    grid-row: 2;
}
.grid-position-1-3 {
    grid-column: 1;
    grid-row: 3;
}
.grid-position-2-3 {
    grid-column: 2;
    grid-row: 3;
}
.grid-position-3-3 {
    grid-column: 3;
    grid-row: 3;
}
.grid-position-1-4 {
    grid-column: 1;
    grid-row: 4;
}
.grid-position-2-4 {
    grid-column: 2;
    grid-row: 4;
}
.grid-position-3-4 {
    grid-column: 3;
    grid-row: 4;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="panel">
        <div class="top-panel">
            <div class="grid-position-1-1"><!-- of top-panel-->
                <p id="paragraph-1"></p>
            </div>
            <div class="grid-position-2-1"><!-- of top-panel-->
                <p id="paragraph-2"></p>
            </div>
            <div class="grid-position-3-1"><!-- of top-panel-->
                <p id="paragraph-3"></p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="middle-panel">
            <p id="another-paragraph"></p>
        </div>
        <div class="button-panel">
            <div class="grid-position-1-1"><!-- of button-panel-->
                <button id="button-1" class="input-button" value=x>x</button>
            </div>
            <div class="grid-position-2-1">
                <button id="button-2" class="input-button" value=x>x</button>
            </div>
            <div class="grid-position-3-1">
                <button id="button-3" class="input-button" value=x>x</button>
            </div>
            <div class="grid-position-1-2">
                <button id="button-4" class="input-button" value=x>x</button>
            </div>
            <div class="grid-position-2-2">
                <button id="button-5" class="input-button" value=x>x</button>
            </div>
            <div class="grid-position-3-2">
                <button id="button-6" class="input-button" value=x>x</button>
            </div>
            <div class="grid-position-1-3">
                <button id="button-7" class="input-button" value=x>x</button>
            </div>
            <div class="grid-position-2-3">
                <button id="button-8" class="input-button" value=x>x</button>
            </div>
            <div class="grid-position-3-3">
                <button id="button-9" class="input-button" value=x>x</button>
            </div>
            <div class="grid-position-1-4">
                <button id="button-10" class="input-button" value=x>x</button>
            </div>
            <div class="grid-position-2-4">
                <button id="button-10" class="input-button" value=x>x</button>
            </div>
            <div class="grid-position-3-4">
                <button id="button-10" class="input-button" value=x>x</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Code also https://github.com/rawcane/panel-example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You grid container is set to `<div class="panel">`:

```
.panel {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: 80px 80px 1fr;
}
```

But the three areas you reference in your question:

- `.top-panel`
- `.grid-position-2-1`
- `.grid-position-3-1`

are not children of the grid container. They are grandchildren of `.panel`.

Therefore, they are not grid items.

The scope of a [**grid formatting context**](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-grid-layout/#grid-model) is limited to the parent-child relationship.

This means that a grid container is always the parent and a grid item is always the child. Grid properties work only within this relationship.

As stated in the spec:

> [**6. Grid
>   Items**](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-grid-layout/#grid-items)
>
> Each in-flow child of a grid container becomes a grid item.

Descendants of a grid container beyond the children are not grid items and will not accept grid properties. Also, as implied in the spec language above, [children that are out-of-flow](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-grid-layout/#static-position) (i.e., absolutely positioned) are not grid items, either.

Bottom line: You will always need to apply `display: grid` or `display: inline-grid` to a parent in order for grid properties to work on the child.

Comment: So I actually introduced the extra level in order to try and resolve the issue. Posted code without this which still doesn't work.

Comment: Because you have not defined a height on the container, the height of the container defaults to `height: auto` (the height of the content). This leaves no extra space for the `1fr` to consume. If you want viewport height, then specify that.  https://jsfiddle.net/3wLd1hz4/

Comment: Ah got it thanks. And the reason it is not required for width is just luck/to do with there only being one column?

Comment: If you want a grid container to shrink-wrap the content, use `display: inline-grid`.